# how to undo a git stash to get to a position before the stash

Tags: git

I did a git stash and lost changes to some of my files. There were a number of files that changed in the local repo before I did the git stash. After the stash it changed some of the files. how can I undo the stash to get the previous state before doing git stash without losing all of my files that are not changed my stash

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
git stash pop
```

it'll bring back the changes. If there's conflicts, git will ask you to resolve them.